# How to get a list of textarea's value inside the controller?

Tags: angularjs

I know in AngularJS you can't manipulate the DOM from the controller, the bridge between the controller and the view is the $scope. I'm creating a few textareas based on an ajax call's result.

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fieldNames">
   <label for="{{ field }}">Description of {{ field }} field</label>
       <textarea class="form-control" id="{{ field }}" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
```

I want to have a plus textarea below these where after clicking on a button, I would parse every textareas' text to Wiki format right into this textarea.

I'm reading the AngularJS documentation, but didn't find a solution yet. If I would give an `ng-model={{ field }}` to the textareas, how can I get all of them's value?

If I could give a variable after `$scope.` then there wouldn't be any problem, but I assume it's not possible this way.

In jQuery I got all the textareas except the last one  `$.each($('textarea'),function(key,val){ result += val.value; ... }` and added their values to the string I write out to the Wiki textarea.

Is there a similar way in AngularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `ngModel` doesn't support interpolation syntax {{ expression }}.

Your data should be formed as array of objects:

```
$scope.fieldNames = [
 { id:1, name:"textarea1" , text:"" },
 { id:2, name:"textarea2" , text:"" },
 { id:3, name:"textarea3" , text:"" }
]
```

Then you can do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fieldNames">
   <label for="{{ field.id }}">Description of {{ field.name }} field</label>
       <textarea ng-model="field.text" class="form-control" id="{{ field.id }}" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
```